# Rails 5 - iterate until field matches regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app that I am building to learn Rails and Ruby, I have below iteration/loop which is not functioning as it should.

### What am I trying to achieve?

I am trying to find the business partner (within only the active once (uses a scope)) where the value of the field `business_partner.bank_account` is contained in the field `self_extracted_data` and then set the business partner found as self.sender (self here is a `Document`).

So once a match is found, I want to end the loop. A case exists where no match is found and sender = nil so a user needs to set it manually.

What happens now, is that on which ever record of the object I save (it is called as a callback before_save), it uses the last identified business partner as sender and the method does not execute again.

### Current code:

```
def set_sender
 BusinessPartner.active.where.not(id: self.receiver_id).each do |business_partner|
    bp_bank_account = business_partner.bank_account.gsub(/\s+/, '')
    rgx = /(?<!\w)(#{Regexp.escape(bp_bank_account)})?(?!\‌​w)/
    if self.extracted_data.gsub(/\s+/, '') =~ rgx
      self.sender = business_partner
    else
      self.sender = nil
    end
 end
end
```

Thanks for helping me understand how to do this kind of case.
p.s. have the pickaxe book here yet this is so much that some help / guidance would be great. The regex works.

---

Using feedback from @moveson, this code works:

```
def match_with_extracted_data?(rgx_to_match)
  extracted_data.gsub(/\s+/, '') =~ rgx_to_match
end

def set_sender
  self.sender_id = matching_business_partner.try(:id) #unless self.sender.id.present? # Returns nil if no matching_business_partner exists
end

def matching_business_partner
  BusinessPartner.active.excluding_receiver(receiver_id).find { |business_partner| sender_matches?(business_partner) }
end

def sender_matches?(business_partner)
  rgx_registrations = /(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})|(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.registration.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})|(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.vat_id.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})/
  match_with_extracted_data?(rgx_registrations)
end
```

Comment: This method seems to be doing a lot of things. It's hard to understand exactly what is happening, which may explain why you aren't getting a lot of bites on this question. You might start by breaking it up into several pieces, each with one very specific job. This will help both you and others understand your code. For starters, you might do: `def other_business_partners; BusinessPartner.active.where.not(id: receiver_id); end`. That eliminates the `unless` condition, (and makes clear that you are comparing an ActiveRecord object to an integer).

Comment: adjusted the code to simplify. From where do you take I am comparing an ActiveRecord object to an integer? (sender is an association to ActiveRecord object BusinessPartner)

Comment: Your old code included the line: `unless business_partner == self.receiver_id`. `business_partner` was a block variable representing each record in an ActiveRecord Relation, whereas (I assume) `self.receiver_id` returns an integer. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby you generally want to avoid loops and `#each` and long, procedural methods in favor of Enumerable iterators like `#map`, `#find`, and `#select`, and short, descriptive methods that each do a single job. Without knowing more about your project I can't be sure exactly what will work, but I think you want something like this:

```
# /models/document.rb

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  def set_sender
    self.sender = matching_business_partner.try(:id) || BusinessPartner.active.default.id
  end

  def matching_business_partners
    other_business_partners.select { |business_partner| account_matches?(business_partner) }
  end

  def matching_business_partner
    matching_business_partners.first
  end

  def other_business_partners
    BusinessPartner.excluding_receiver_id(receiver_id)
  end

  def account_matches?(business_partner)
    rgx = /(?<!\w)(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.stripped_bank_account)})?(?!\‌​w)/
    data_matches_bank_account?(rgx)
  end

  def data_matches_bank_account?(rgx)
    extracted_data.gsub(/\s+/, '') =~ rgx
  end

end

# /models/business_partner.rb

class BusinessPartner < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :excluding_receiver_id, -> (receiver_id) { where.not(id: receiver_id) }

  def stripped_bank_account
    bank_account.gsub(/\s+/, '')
  end

end
```

Note that I am assigning an integer id, rather than an ActiveRecord object, to `self.sender`. I think that's what you want.

I didn't try to mess with the database relations here, but it does seem like Document could include a `belongs_to :business_partner`, which would give you the benefit of Rails methods to help you find one from the other.

EDIT: Added `Document#matching_business_partners` method and changed `Document#set_sender` method to return nil if no `matching_business_partner` exists.

EDIT: Added `BusinessPartner.active.default.id` as the return value if no `matching_business_partner` exists.

Comment: Correct, Document has a `belongs_to :sender, class_name: "BusinessPartner"` as well as a `belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "BusinessPartner"` relationship with BusinessPartner. While I think I understand what you are saying / doing (I do like its purity) - use simple to understand methods - it appears to be leading to many, many single / few line methods. Also I now I have a bit of difficulty seeing how to handle the case if no match is found or adding a second match. Again, am new to Rails and Ruby (even to coding ;-) )

Comment: Good questions! Yes, this leads to many small methods. That is exactly what you want. It may look strange if you are used to looking at long procedures, but it will greatly simplify your code and make it super easy to extend. As an example, it took me about 60 seconds to add both features you requested. `Document#set_sender` now returns `nil` if no match is found, and `Document#matching_business_partners` returns an array of all matches.

Comment: okay understand the many simple methods concept. Still got questions popping up: e.g. I do see many cases (e.g. rails casts) where it is daisy chained. e.g. something like `self.sender = matching_business_partners.first.try(:id)` - you added an additional method for it. And I need to explain better what I meant with a second match: I have more (unique) criteria that I can use to identify the sender (either or). Next to bank_account, there is vat_id or company_registration. More fuzzy would be internet domain or email addresses. So that should go into account_matches?

Comment: Sure--it's fine to chain methods, and the code will run just fine. If it's doing what you want it to do, then you're good. In this case, the code wasn't doing what you wanted it to do, and it was hard to see why, so I pulled it apart using OO best practices. If you want to see a master working through a similar process, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE). To answer your question, yes, now that you have an `account_matches?` method, it sounds like that's a good place for your new match criteria. If `account_matches?` gets too big, pull it apart as well.

Comment: going to watch the master at work at a quiet moment ;-) - remain 2 questions 1) how could I set `self.sender` to a default value (`BusinessPartner.active.default.take`) if `matching_business_partner.try(:id)` is nil? - and 2) how to simplify (DRY) this (the regex for `account_matches`) : `rgx_registrations = /(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.bank_account.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})|(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.registration.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})|(#{Regexp.escape(business_partner.vat_id.gsub(/\s+/, ''))})/` (my line of thinking still too "spaghetti" :-) )

Comment: See edits above for the first answer. The double-pipe operator `||` means, return the first value unless it is nil, in which case return the second value. Ruby is so very nice! You already have the `stripped_bank_account` method that performs that `.gsub` action. Make it a generic method: `def stripped_text(text); text.gsub(/\s+/, ''); end`. Then call it with `stripped_text(business_partner.bank_account)` and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127845/discussion-between-moveson-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).